# How can I have PHPCS run our Joomla ruleset.xml in Travis-CI?

Tags: joomla, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm working to integrate the Joomla CMS with Travis-CI as we expand our CI coverage and I'm running into issues with using PHPCS on Travis-CI.  As shown [here](https://travis-ci.org/mbabker/joomla-cms/builds/6863344) PHPCS registers the sniffs but when it scans for files to parse, 0 files are queued.  The GitHub branch is on my fork [here](https://github.com/mbabker/joomla-cms/compare/travis).  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally figured this out.  The issue I ran into dealt with the use of `<exclude-pattern>` tags.